# Configuring columns when adding CSV file to QGIS

Tags: csv, import, latitude-longitude, excel, delimiter

I want to load a csv file into QGIS, and the data in QGIS as point layer. I have tried to use this function:

Layer ► Add layer ► Add Delimited Text Layer.

When Im loading the file name, the data comes like this in the box:

[image: Creating a layer from a delimited text file]

All the data is just in one column. Latude and longitude should be x,y values. I had GHI, Latitude and Longitude in different columns in excel, like this:

[image]

To make the csv file I saved as "CSV (comma delimited).

So how can I load the csv file correctly? I havent done a operation like this before.

Comment: Set the option "custom delimiters" and choose your seperator (semi-colon).

Comment: Your data seems to be "semicolon separated values", not "comma separated values". Select "custom delimiters".

Answer (score 7):

Since your data is delimited by semicolons, you must select "Custom Delimiter" then "Semicolon".